# Computer crashes on armature set automatic weights

Tags: armature, vertex-weights

Not sure why it does this. Scoured the internet trying to figure out what's wrong with my mesh if someone could help that'd be awesome

I'm still at amateur level.

Specs

```
i5 4460
gtx 1060
16gb ram
```

C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender>blender -bC:\Users\slend\Documents\Benny{problemwithAutomaticWeightArmacher}.blend-d
Read prefs: C:\Users\slend\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\config\userpref.blend
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python
path not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\slend\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\DNOISE__init__.py", line 206, in loaddnoisesettings
    fmutils.disablepasses()
  File "C:\Users\slend\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\DNOISE\fmutils.py", line 204, in disablepasses
    bpy.context.scene.view_layers[0].use_pass_diffuse_color = False
AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'view_layers'
path not found
unknown argument, loading as file: -bC:\Users\slend\Documents\Benny{problemwithAutomaticWeightArmacher}.blend-d
Error: Cannot read file 'C:\Users\slend\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\DNOISE-bC:\Users\slend\Documents\Benny{problemwithAutomaticWeightArmacher}.blend-d': Invalid argument
... opened default scene instead; saving will write to C:\Users\slend\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\DNOISE-bC:\Users\slend\Documents\Benny{problemwithAutomaticWeightArmacher}.blend-d
Read blend: C:\Users\slend\Documents\Benny{problemwithAutomaticWeightArmacher}.blend
scripts disabled for "C:\Users\slend\Documents\Benny{problemwithAutomaticWeightArmacher}.blend", skipping 'rig_ui.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\slend\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\DNOISE__init__.py", line 206, in loaddnoisesettings
    fmutils.disablepasses()
  File "C:\Users\slend\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\DNOISE\fmutils.py", line 204, in disablepasses
    bpy.context.scene.view_layers[0].use_pass_diffuse_color = False
AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'view_layers'
path not found

**fixed it if anyone else is having trouble like this try simplifying your mesh using the decimate tool.

Comment: Could you run blender from cmd with the -d flag set? So the command would look like this (from inside your blender folder): blender -b C:\Users\DruJones\Desktop\important.blend -d. Then try to reproduce the error and edit your question with whatever error appears in the cmd. Also please add your pc specs, as that can give hints

Comment: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender>-bC:\Users\slend\Documents\Benny{problemwithAutomaticWeightArmacher}.blend-d
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: im not sure why but this is what i typed in cmd im sure its the right path

Comment: thanks for the help btw i honestly thought it might be a lost cause

Comment: here ya go i got that down pat i updated the error message now in the main box

Comment: https://paste.pics/65d2862083128dd2ad5882c3886abbfc

Comment: theres the png of my .blend file its too big to upload for some reason

Comment: Error seems to come from the DNOISE addon, try disabling it. Please make a screenshot next time, that error message is very hard to read

Comment: i just tried this and it didnt work unfortunately ill provide a link to the .blend file

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3i7aoesh76s16xz/Benny%7BproblemwithAutomaticWeightArmacher%7D.blend?dl=0